# Linux command line ${RANDOM:0:3}

Tags: linux

I have been reading about Linux command line and have come across this:

${RANDOM:0:3}

This is supposed to create 4 random numbers but sometimes it only makes 3, is there any reason for this? Also I have only been involved with Python and so am not sure why this command needs the $ sign at the start.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumptions are **false**, (and the way to achieve your goal is totally **wrong**) this is **not** supposed to "create" 4 random numbers, but just display the 3 first digits of an integer between 0 and 32767 (small integer). The second and the third ones can off course be missing if the integer is less than 100 or 10!

If you would like to get a  [pseudo random](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness) integer from the command line, [python](/questions/tagged/python) (like mentioned in your original POST) is a good way :

```
 python -c 'import random; print(random.randint(0, 68))'
```

(between 0 and 68)

Comment: Python is so beautiful. I see so RANDOM generates a number and then 0:3 display the first 4 digits unless the number is smaller then 1000.

Comment: I was supposed to put :0:4, my mistake.

Comment: As I said, the way to achieve your goal is totally wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`${parameter:offset:length}` is taking substring from `parameter` starting at `offset`, `length` characters long. So your code generates *one* random number and takes first three digits of it.

There is no way it can produce 4 characters, but easily can produce 2 or one: if random number is less than 100 or less than 10.

Comment: Ahh yes I just asked about this, it does actually print 4 characters most of the time, but like you say if the number is less then 100 or 10 then it will only print 2 or 1.